# Json_Normalize, targeting nested columns within a specific column?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm working with an API trying to currently pull data out of it. The challenge I'm having is that the majority of the columns are straight forward and not nested, with the exception of a CustomFields column which has all the various custom fields used located in a list per record.

Using json_normalize is there a way to target a nested column to flatten it? I'm trying to fetch and use all the data available from the API but one nested column in particular is causing a headache.

The JSON data when retrieved from the API looks like the following. This is just for one customer profile,

```
[{'EmailAddress': 'an_email@gmail.com', 'Name': 'Al Smith’, 'Date': '2020-05-26 14:58:00', 'State': 'Active', 'CustomFields': [{'Key': '[Location]', 'Value': 'HJGO'}, {'Key': '[location_id]', 'Value': '34566'}, {'Key': '[customer_id]', 'Value': '9051'}, {'Key': '[status]', 'Value': 'Active'}, {'Key': '[last_visit.1]', 'Value': '2020-02-19'}]
```

Using json_normalize,

```
payload = json_normalize(payload_json['Results'])
```

Here are the results when I run the above code,

[image]

Ideally, here is what I would like the final result to look like,

[image: What I would like the results to look like]

I think I just need to work with the record_path and meta parameters but I'm not totally understanding how they work.

Any ideas? Or would using json_normalize not work in this situation?

Comment: `json_normalize(payload_json['Results'], record_path = ['CustomFields'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You have square brackets in your JSON, that's why you see those [ ] :

```
d = [{'EmailAddress': 'an_email@gmail.com', 'Name': 'Al Smith', 'Date': '2020-05-26 14:58:00', 'State': 'Active', 'CustomFields': [{'Key': '[Location]', 'Value': 'HJGO'}, {'Key': '[location_id]', 'Value': '34566'}, {'Key': '[customer_id]', 'Value': '9051'}, {'Key': '[status]', 'Value': 'Active'}, {'Key': '[last_visit.1]', 'Value': '2020-02-19'}]}]
df = pd.json_normalize(d, record_path=['CustomFields'], meta=[['EmailAddress'], ['Name'], ['Date'], ['State']])
df = df.pivot_table(columns='Key', values='Value', index=['EmailAddress', 'Name'], aggfunc='sum')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
Key                         [Location] [customer_id] [last_visit.1] [location_id] [status]
EmailAddress       Name
an_email@gmail.com Al Smith       HJGO          9051     2020-02-19         34566   Active
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you!